# PHP opening times & embassy holidays

Tags: php, mysql, time, timetable

I've been using this code:

```
 $rawsql = "SELECT 
*
FROM 
    _erc_foffices n 
INNER JOIN 
    _erc_openings o ON n.id = o.branch_id AND o.dotw = DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE()) 
INNER JOIN 
    _erc_openings_times t ON o.id = t.opening_id
WHERE 
(
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(), ' ', t.open)) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(), ' ', t.close)) 
) 
AND 
(
    n.id = %d
)
;";

$sql = sprintf($rawsql, mysql_real_escape_string($id));

$result = mysql_query($sql);

/*These if & while statements decide whether or not the information should be displayed. If no results are returned from the query above then an alternative message is shown.*/

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

        echo "<div class='address'><p>" . $row["title"] . "<br/>";
        echo $row["address_1"] . "<br/> " . $row["address_2"] . "<br/> " . $row["address_3"] . "<br/> " . $row["address_4"] . "<br/> " . $row["address_5"] . "</p>";
        echo "<div class='buttons'><img src='http://localhost/erc/images/texttouser_button.png'/><br/><a href='" . $row["url"] . "' target='blank'><img src='http://localhost/erc/images/website_button.png'/></a></div></div>";
        echo "<div class='email'>" . $row["email"] . "</div>";
        $extra_notes = $row["extra"];

    }
} else {

        $embassy_closed = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM _erc_foffices WHERE id = '$embassy_id'");

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($embassy_closed))
                      {

        echo "<div class='address'><p>" . $row["title"] . "<br/>";
        echo $row["address_1"] . "<br/> " . $row["address_2"] . "<br/> " . $row["address_3"] . "<br/> " . $row["address_4"] . "<br/> " . $row["address_5"] . " <font color='red'>The embassy is closed.</font></p>";
        echo "<div class='buttons'><img src='http://localhost/erc/images/texttouser_button.png'/><br/><a href='" . $row["url"] . "' target='blank'><img src='http://localhost/erc/images/website_button.png'/></a></div></div>";
        echo "<div class='email'>" . $row["email"] . "</div>";
        $extra_notes = $row["extra"];


                      }


}
```

which takes the opening times for embassies from a database and decides whether or not the embassy is currently open. If it's not, a message saying 'The embassy is closed' is shown. Now I need to add in public holidays, so I have altered the query to look like this:

```
    $rawsql = "SELECT 
    *
    FROM 
        _erc_foffices n 
    INNER JOIN 
        _erc_openings o ON n.id = o.branch_id AND o.dotw = DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE()) 
    INNER JOIN 
        _erc_openings_times t ON o.id = t.opening_id
        LEFT JOIN 
    _erc_holidays h ON h.branch_id = n.id
    WHERE 
    (
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(), ' ', t.open)) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(CURRENT_DATE(), ' ', t.close)) 
    ) 
    AND 
    (
        n.id = %d
    )
        AND
(
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) 
    NOT BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(h.begins_at) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(h.ends_at)
)
        ;";
```

but this just outputs the address/email etc twice.

Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong please?

Thanks for any help

Edit: I have fixed this now, just used a 2nd query and if/else loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used a 2nd query and if/else loop and it's working as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't profess to be an expert and your joins look very complicated, but in my experience if you're getting duplicates in your query then you haven't grouped properly and I can't see a GROUP BY at all in your query.

Hope that helps.

By the way... where did you source your public holiday data? I'm looking for the exact same thing at the moment which is how I came across this post.

Comment: Hi Dave, a member of our staff is going through all of the embassy websites and gathering the data manually.